# Not Drawing Until I Move Something

Tags: java, swing, paint

In the game I am trying to make, the images are not painting until I move the character.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class ForgottenMain extends JPanel implements KeyListener,MouseListener{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 35;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4926251405849574401L;
    public static BufferedImage attic,flashlight,player,killer;
    public static boolean up,down,left,right,inAttic;
    public static int px,py,kx,ky;
    public static int spawnLocation;
    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Forgotten");
    public static void main(String[] args){
        inAttic = true;
        px = 600;
        py = 400;
        frame.setSize(1200,800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(new ForgottenMain());
    }
    public ForgottenMain(){
        init();
    }
    public void init(){
        setSize(1200,800);
        setVisible(true);
        frame.addKeyListener(this);
        frame.addMouseListener(this);
        try{    
            player = ImageIO.read(new File("char.png"));
            flashlight = ImageIO.read(new File("flashlightimage.png"));
            attic = ImageIO.read(new File("attic.png"));
            killer = ImageIO.read(new File("killer.png"));
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Gameloop
          new javax.swing.Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    gameLoop();
                 }
              }).start();   
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        int fx = px - 1033;
        int fy = py - 635;
        kx = 500;
        ky = 500;
        // Removes the flickering of the images
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        // Resets the screen to make sure that it only shows the character once
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, 1200, 800);
        // Draws the background attic
        g2.drawImage(attic,0,0,this);
        // Draws the player
        g2.drawImage(player, px, py, this);
        // Draws the Serial Killer
        g2.drawImage(killer, kx, ky, this);
        // Draws the flashlight
        g2.drawImage(flashlight, fx, fy, this);
        System.out.println(px + " " + py);
    }
    public void gameLoop(){
        if(up == true && py > 88){
            py-=4;
            repaint();
        }
        if(down == true && py < 604){
            py+=4;
            repaint();
        }
        if(left == true && px > 80){
            px-=4;
            repaint();
        }
        if(right == true && px < 1028){
            px+=4;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("MouseLocation: " + arg0.getX() + ", " + arg0.getY());
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 87){
            up = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 83){
            down = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 65){
            left = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 68){
            right = true;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 87){
            up = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 83){
            down = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 65){
            left = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 68){
            right = false;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

For example, in my game, you move the character with the keys W, A, S, and D. When the program runs, it shows a blank screen, and doesn't show everything that should be drawing, until I press W, A, S, or D.

If I left anything out that would be helpful let me know.  I thought maybe it was trying to paint before the images were initialized, so I put a repaint after I initialized them, and it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that since none of the `boolean` values `up`, `down`, `left` or `right` is `true`, the logic in `gameLoop()` won't call for a `repaint()`! This can be fixed by explicitly calling `repaint()` from the `main(String[])` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    inAttic = true;
    px = 600;
    py = 400;
    //frame.setSize(1200, 800);
    ForgottenMain fm = new ForgottenMain();
    frame.add(fm);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    fm.repaint();
}
```

---

### Other tips:

- Wrong method: `public void paint(Graphics g){ ..` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ super.paintComponent(g); ..` (calling the super method is also important).
- `frame.setSize(1200,800); .. setSize(1200,800);` This is wrong, the panel will be less than 1200 x 800 because of the frame decorations, and layout managers typically ignore the size over the preferred size. To fix it:

  1. `@Override public Dimension getPreferredSize() { return new Dimension(1200,800); }` in the painting surface (the `JPanel`).
  2. Add the panel to the frame.
  3. Call `frame.pack();` after adding the component and calling `frame.setResizable(false);`, but before `frame.setVisible(true);` ..
- `player = ImageIO.read(new File("char.png"));` Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now. An [embedded-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) must be accessed by URL rather than file. See the [info. page for embedded resource](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.
- `if (e.getKeyCode() == 87) {` Don't use 'magic numbers' instead use the `KeyEvent.VK_..`. Not only does it provide compile time checking, but is also better documentation for other programmers.

Comment: No problem :) Very nice answer 1+

Comment: Thanks, it worked! And thanks for the tips, I'll keep all of that in mind :)